# How to make files in S3 publicly accessible but block public uploads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

For an S3 bucket is there a way to allow public get access but restrict public uploads? i.e. everyone can view the files but only my server (IAM credentials) can upload.

My bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PrivatePut",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123:user/Access"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I try save this bucket policy I get an access denied error
[image: Error]

My CORS policy:

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://example.com"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

Not sure what to de/select for the `Block public access` settings

Currently they're all checked except for `Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies`

Also, adding `"AllowedOrigins": ["http://localhost:3000"]` to the CORS policy seems suss.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding a Bucket Policy to an Amazon S3 bucket, **turn off *both* "Block public access" options** that mention "public bucket or access point policies". This should be sufficient to fix your issue.

Generally, granting public access is done via a bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicGet",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Granting access to a **specific user** is best done **as a policy on the IAM User themselves** rather than the bucket policy:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PrivatePut",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::foo/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

There is no need to modify CORS settings unless you are experiencing a specific error that mentions CORS.